# How to load a different version of linux kernel?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, configuration

I am currently using ubuntu 14.04 with the kernel 3.13.0-37-generic, I want to try booting from another kernel 3.17.01 (latest stable release).

I have downloaded and built the 3.17.01 kernel from source. Based on what I have understood so far, I need to copy bzImage file to /boot folder and change the grub config file accordingly.

Is this the correct way to do so ? If yes, then can anyone tell me how to configure the grub so that I may be able to boot from both 3.13 and 3.17 kernel (2 options in grub menu)

If not , then what are the steps to do so ?

I am using grub 2 currently.

Comment: Not going to post this as an official answer since I'm unsure, but I think once the image is in /boot, a nice `sudo update-grub` should take care of the rest.

Comment: @MGodby I don't think that's possible, because there are several other important files present in the `/boot` folder regarding the currently running kernel. I don't think grub will be generating those files. Also, on some forums it was written that I need to manually generate initramfs. Not sure, how to do that though.

Comment: Ah, yes, the initramfs do need generating first. GRUB supports multiple images once they are present, however. I guess the main part of what I wanted to say is that I don't think you need to manually update grub.conf. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: You can get the .debs from [the mainline PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.17.1-utopic/), and install with `dpkg -i` or double clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having configured the kernel, you can use `make-kpkg` to compile it and make a .deb package for easy installation and de-installation. If you install such a package, the new kernel is automatically added to your grub config.